# Works in Chrome but not in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

The Navigation Bar works in Chrome but not in Internet Explorer? Any suggestions as too why?

The Code itself works in both Internet Explorer and Chrome when run from computer but wont load when put into my online website editor. [Here is the link.](http://secureshop.co.uk/epages/950004767.sf)

**CSS:**

```
        /* Line Brake (Top Bar) */
        .wrap {position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 145px;}
        .wrap .all {text-decoration: none; list-style: none; position: absolute; top: 4em; left: 14em; padding: 0 0; z-index: 600;}
        .all #hidding1 {display: none; text-decoration: none; list-style: none; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; width: 500px;}
        .all #hidding1 a {display: none; text-decoration: none; list-style: none; color: #222; font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px; 
                          display: table-cell; height: 21px;}
        .all #hide {display: none; text-decoration: none; list-style: none; font-family: Arial; width: 300px;}
        .all #hide a {display: none; text-decoration: none; list-style: none; color: #1c68ac; font-weight: bolder; font-size: 12px; display: table-cell; 
                      height: 21px;}
        .all #hide a:hover {color: #44a2f7;}
        .all #hidding2 {display: none; text-decoration: none; list-style: none; position: absolute; top: -0.4em; left: -16em; z-index: 500; width: 150px;}
        .all #hidding2 a {display: none; text-decoration: none; list-style: none; font-weight: bolder; list-style: none; 
                          font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; color: #222; display: table-cell; height: 25px;}
        /* Line Brake (Header) */
        .headerdiv .headerlist {text-decoration: none; list-style: none; font-family: 'Archivo Narrow',sans-serif; 
                                position: absolute; top: 5.5em; left: 10.5em;}
        .headerdiv .headerlist a {text-decoration: none; list-style: none; font-size: 15px; font-family: 'Archivo Narrow',sans-serif; color: #000}
        .platewrap {margin: 129px -5px;}

    .backbox {padding: 0; margin: 0; position: absolute; top: 100px; left: 145px; width: 642px; height: 34px; float:left; background-color: #000;}

    img.headerlogoBTN {width: 145px; height: 145px; padding: 0; margin: 0; position: absolute; top: -5px; left: 0px;
        background: url(http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/08b1/rvw9cjd6fvwf716fg.jpg?size_id=2) 0 0;}

    img.headerlogoBTNOVER {visibility: hidden; width: 145px; height: 145px; padding: 0; margin: 0; position: absolute; top: -5px; left: 0px;
        background: url(http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/d567/1u4h4b2oro8ae24fg.jpg?size_id=2) 0 0;}

    img.plate1 {width: 238px; height: 65px; float: left;
        background: url(http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/c808/k74jx82dokpc3h9fg.jpg?size_id=3) 0 0;}

    img.plate2 {width: 183px; height: 65px; float: left;
        background: url(http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/374d/hb5igbcffv3sxbrfg.jpg?size_id=2) 0 0;}

    img.plate3 {width: 183px; height: 65px; float: left;
        background: url(http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/c405/2y6b2ped2du8223fg.jpg?size_id=2) 0 0;}

    img.plate4 {width: 183px; height: 65px; float: left;
        background: url(http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/e799/kj4oxmeu5f8nxx2fg.jpg?size_id=2) 0 0;}

    img.background {width: 642px; height:418px; padding: 0; margin: 0; position: absolute; top: 34px; left: 0px; box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #555;
        background: url(http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/0009/wk4di19bo79n9s8fg.jpg?size_id=5) 0 0;}

    img.sublistBTN {width: 170px; height: 30px; padding: 0; margin: 0; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;
        background: url(http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/909d/24b3kx4k77m2xkyfg.jpg?size_id=2) 0 0;}

    img.allcategoriesBTN {width:140px; height:34px; padding: 0; margin: 0; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;
        background: url(http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/2a45/702142qw7au3hdufg.jpg?size_id=2) 0 0;}    

    img.allcategoriesBTNOVER {width:140px; height:34px; padding: 0; margin: 0; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;
        background: url(http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/fd56/22sleb09keyvun0fg.jpg?size_id=2) 0 0;}

    img.allbrandsBTN {width:115px; height:34px; padding: 0; margin: 0 142px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;
        background: url(http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/cea2/j2lb11zd8vetcs5fg.jpg?size_id=2) 0 0;}

    img.allbrandsBTNOVER {width:115px; height:34px; padding: 0; margin: 0 142px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;
        background: url(http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/2245/r7jhtriatti4iczfg.jpg?size_id=2) 0 0;}

    img.mtbbikesBTN {width:100px; height:34px; padding: 0; margin: 0 267px; position: absolute; top: 0px;left: 0px;
        background: url(http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/77be/d5ycaifdo5wcd2efg.jpg?size_id=2) 0 0;}

    img.mtbbikesBTNOVER {width:100px; height:34px; padding: 0; margin: 0 267px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;
        background: url(http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/dc5f/5s38tkk4z5v5c2kfg.jpg?size_id=1) 0 0;}

    img.roadbikesBTN {width:108px; height:34px; padding: 0; margin: 0 369px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;
        background: url(http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/62d9/0rvm4tqcp3omcq1fg.jpg?size_id=2) 0 0;}

    img.roadbikesBTNOVER {width:108px; height:34px; padding: 0; margin: 0 369px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;
        background: url(http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/f191/46z460rzq3htu9wfg.jpg?size_id=2) 0 0;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="backbox">
<p>&nbsp;
    </p>
</div>

<div class="headerdiv">
    <ol class="headerlist">
        <li><a>Welcome to our Brand New Website!</a></li>
    </ol>
</div>

<div class="headerlogo">
<img class="headerlogoBTN" src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/08b1/rvw9cjd6fvwf716fg.jpg?size_id=2" /> 
<img class="headerlogoBTNOVER" src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/d567/1u4h4b2oro8ae24fg.jpg?size_id=2" /> 
</div>

<div class="wrap"> 
<img class="allcategoriesBTN" src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/2a45/702142qw7au3hdufg.jpg?size_id=2" /> 
<img class="allcategoriesBTNOVER" id="hidden1" src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/fd56/22sleb09keyvun0fg.jpg?size_id=2" /> 
<img class="background" id="hidden1" src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/0009/wk4di19bo79n9s8fg.jpg?size_id=5" /> 
<img class="sublistBTN" id="hide" src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/909d/24b3kx4k77m2xkyfg.jpg?size_id=2" /> 
<div class="all">
<ol class="fs1header" id="hidding1">
    <li><a>Fork Suspension (All)</a></li>
</ol>
<ol class="c1header" id="hidding1">
    <li><a>Components (All)</a></li>
</ol>
<ol class="wt1header" id="hidding1">
    <li><a>Wheels &amp; Tyres (All)</a></li>
</ol>
<ol class="a1header" id="hidding1">
    <li><a>Accessories (All)</a></li>
</ol>
<ol class="fs1" id="hide" style="-moz-column-count:1; -webkit-column-count:1; column-count:1; -moz-column-gap:30px; -webkit-column-gap:30px; column-gap:30px;">
    <li><a href="">Front Forks Suspension</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Frame Protection</a></li>
</ol>
<ol class="c1" id="hide" style="-moz-column-count:2; -webkit-column-count:2; column-count:2; -moz-column-gap:30px; -webkit-column-gap:30px; column-gap:30px;">
    <li><a href="">Bar End Plugs</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Bar Ends</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Bearings</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Bottom Brackets</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Brake Cables</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Brake/Disc Pads</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Brakes</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Brake Spares</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Cassettes</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Chains</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Crank Bolts</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Derailleurs</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Gear Cables</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Gear Shifters</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Grips</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Handlebars</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Headsets</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Headset Spacers</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Pedals</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Saddles</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Seatclamps</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Seatposts</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Stems</a></li>
</ol>
<ol class="wt1" id="hide" style="-moz-column-count:1; -webkit-column-count:1; column-count:1; -moz-column-gap:30px; -webkit-column-gap:30px; column-gap:30px;">
    <li><a href="">Rims</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Rim Tape</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Skewers</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Tubeless Kits</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Tubes</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Tyres</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Valve Caps</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Wheels</a></li>
</ol>
<ol class="a1" id="hide" style="-moz-column-count:1; -webkit-column-count:1; column-count:1; -moz-column-gap:30px; -webkit-column-gap:30px; column-gap:30px;">
    <li><a href="">Bells</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Computers</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Lights</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Locks</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Mudguards</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Pumps</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Stickers</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Water Bottle Cages</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Water Bottles</a></li>
</ol>
<div class="list1" id="hidding2">
    <ol class="forks1">
        <a href="">Front Suspension</a></ol>
    <ol class="comp1">
        <a href="">Components</a></ol>
    <ol class="wheel1">
        <a href="">Wheels &amp; Tyres</a></ol>
    <ol class="acc1">
        <a href="">Accessories</a></ol>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="wrap"> 
<img class="allbrandsBTN" src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/cea2/j2lb11zd8vetcs5fg.jpg?size_id=2">
<img class="allbrandsBTNOVER" id="hidden2" src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/2245/r7jhtriatti4iczfg.jpg?size_id=2">
<img class="background" id="hidden2" src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/0009/wk4di19bo79n9s8fg.jpg?size_id=5" /> 
<img class="sublistBTN" id="hide" src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/909d/24b3kx4k77m2xkyfg.jpg?size_id=2" /> 
<div class="all">
<ol class="fs2header" id="hidding1">
    <li><a>Fork Suspension (By Brand)</a></li>
</ol>
<ol class="c2header" id="hidding1">
    <li><a>Components (By Brand)</a></li>
</ol>
<ol class="wt2header" id="hidding1">
    <li><a>Wheels &amp; Tyres (By Brand)</a></li>
</ol>
<ol class="a2header" id="hidding1">
    <li><a>Accessories (By Brand)</a></li>
</ol>
<ol class="fs2" id="hide" style="-moz-column-count:1; -webkit-column-count:1; column-count:1; -moz-column-gap:30px; -webkit-column-gap:30px; column-gap:30px;">
    <li><a href="">Front Forks Suspension</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Frame Protection</a></li>
</ol>
<ol class="c2" id="hide" style="-moz-column-count:2; -webkit-column-count:2; column-count:2; -moz-column-gap:70px; -webkit-column-gap:70px; column-gap:70px;">
    <li><a href="">Bar End Plugs</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Bar Ends</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Bearings</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Bottom Brackets</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Brake Cables</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Brake/Disc Pads</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Brakes</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Brake Spares</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Cassettes</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Chains</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Crank Bolts</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Derailleurs</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Gear Cables</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Gear Shifters</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Grips</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Handlebars</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Headsets</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Headset Spacers</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Pedals</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Saddles</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Seatclamps</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Seatposts</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Stems</a></li>
</ol>
<ol class="wt2" id="hide" style="-moz-column-count:1; -webkit-column-count:1; column-count:1; -moz-column-gap:30px; -webkit-column-gap:30px; column-gap:30px;">
    <li><a href="">Rims</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Rim Tape</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Skewers</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Tubeless Kits</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Tubes</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Tyres</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Valve Caps</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Wheels</a></li>
</ol>
<ol class="a2" id="hide" style="-moz-column-count:1; -webkit-column-count:1; column-count:1; -moz-column-gap:30px; -webkit-column-gap:30px; column-gap:30px;">
    <li><a href="">Bells</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Computers</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Lights</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Locks</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Mudguards</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Pumps</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Stickers</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Water Bottle Cages</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Water Bottles</a></li>
</ol>
<div class="list2" id="hidding2">
    <ol class="forks2">
        <a href="">Front Suspension</a></ol>
    <ol class="comp2">
        <a href="">Components</a></ol>
    <ol class="wheel2">
        <a href="">Wheels &amp; Tyres</a></ol>
    <ol class="acc2">
        <a href="">Accessories</a></ol>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="wrap"> 
<img class="mtbbikesBTN" src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/77be/d5ycaifdo5wcd2efg.jpg?size_id=2">
<img class="mtbbikesBTNOVER" id="hidden3" src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/dc5f/5s38tkk4z5v5c2kfg.jpg?size_id=1"> 
<img class="background" id="hidden3" src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/0009/wk4di19bo79n9s8fg.jpg?size_id=5" /> 
<img class="sublistBTN" id="hide" src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/909d/24b3kx4k77m2xkyfg.jpg?size_id=2" /> 
<div class="all">
<ol class="fs3header" id="hidding1">
    <li><a>Fork Suspension (Mountain Bikes)</a></li>
</ol>
<ol class="c3header" id="hidding1">
    <li><a>Components (Mountain Bikes)</a></li>
</ol>
<ol class="wt3header" id="hidding1">
    <li><a>Wheels &amp; Tyres (Mountain Bikes)</a></li>
</ol>
<ol class="a3header" id="hidding1">
    <li><a>Accessories (Mountain Bikes)</a></li>
</ol>
<ol class="fs3" id="hide" style="-moz-column-count:1; -webkit-column-count:1; column-count:1; -moz-column-gap:30px; -webkit-column-gap:30px; column-gap:30px;">
    <li><a href="">Front Forks Suspension</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Frame Protection</a></li>
</ol>
<ol class="c3" id="hide" style="-moz-column-count:2; -webkit-column-count:2; column-count:2; -moz-column-gap:70px; -webkit-column-gap:70px; column-gap:70px;">
    <li><a href="">Bar End Plugs</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Bar Ends</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Bearings</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Bottom Brackets</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Brake Cables</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Brake/Disc Pads</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Brakes</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Brake Spares</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Cassettes</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Chains</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Crank Bolts</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Derailleurs</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Gear Cables</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Gear Shifters</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Grips</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Handlebars</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Headsets</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Headset Spacers</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Pedals</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Saddles</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Seatclamps</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Seatposts</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Stems</a></li>
</ol>
<ol class="wt3" id="hide" style="-moz-column-count:1; -webkit-column-count:1; column-count:1; -moz-column-gap:30px; -webkit-column-gap:30px; column-gap:30px;">
    <li><a href="">Rims</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Rim Tape</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Skewers</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Tubeless Kits</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Tubes</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Tyres</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Valve Caps</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Wheels</a></li>
</ol>
<ol class="a3" id="hide" style="-moz-column-count:1; -webkit-column-count:1; column-count:1; -moz-column-gap:30px; -webkit-column-gap:30px; column-gap:30px;">
    <li><a href="">Bells</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Computers</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Lights</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Locks</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Mudguards</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Pumps</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Stickers</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Water Bottle Cages</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Water Bottles</a></li>
</ol>
<div class="list3" id="hidding2">
    <ol class="forks3">
        <a href="">Front Suspension</a></ol>
    <ol class="comp3">
        <a href="">Components</a></ol>
    <ol class="wheel3">
        <a href="">Wheels &amp; Tyres</a></ol>
    <ol class="acc3">
        <a href="">Accessories</a></ol>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="wrap"> 
<img class="roadbikesBTN" src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/62d9/0rvm4tqcp3omcq1fg.jpg?size_id=2">
<img class="roadbikesBTNOVER" id="hidden4" src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/f191/46z460rzq3htu9wfg.jpg?size_id=2">
<img class="background" id="hidden4" src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/0009/wk4di19bo79n9s8fg.jpg?size_id=5" /> 
<img class="sublistBTN" id="hide" src="http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/909d/24b3kx4k77m2xkyfg.jpg?size_id=2" /> 
<div class="all">
<ol class="fs4header" id="hidding1">
    <li><a>Fork Suspension (Road Bikes)</a></li>
</ol>
<ol class="c4header" id="hidding1">
    <li><a>Components (Road Bikes)</a></li>
</ol>
<ol class="wt4header" id="hidding1">
    <li><a>Wheels &amp; Tyres (Road Bikes)</a></li>
</ol>
<ol class="a4header" id="hidding1">
    <li><a>Accessories (Road Bikes)</a></li>
</ol>
<ol class="fs4" id="hide" style="-moz-column-count:1; -webkit-column-count:1; column-count:1; -moz-column-gap:30px; -webkit-column-gap:30px; column-gap:30px;">
    <li><a href="">Front Forks Suspension</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Frame Protection</a></li>
</ol>
<ol class="c4" id="hide" style="-moz-column-count:2; -webkit-column-count:2; column-count:2; -moz-column-gap:70px; -webkit-column-gap:70px; column-gap:70px;">
    <li><a href="">Bar End Plugs</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Bar Ends</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Bearings</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Bottom Brackets</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Brake Cables</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Brake/Disc Pads</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Brakes</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Brake Spares</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Cassettes</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Chains</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Crank Bolts</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Derailleurs</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Gear Cables</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Gear Shifters</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Grips</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Handlebars</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Headsets</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Headset Spacers</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Pedals</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Saddles</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Seatclamps</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Seatposts</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Stems</a></li>
</ol>
<ol class="wt4" id="hide" style="-moz-column-count:1; -webkit-column-count:1; column-count:1; -moz-column-gap:30px; -webkit-column-gap:30px; column-gap:30px;">
    <li><a href="">Rims</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Rim Tape</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Skewers</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Tubeless Kits</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Tubes</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Tyres</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Valve Caps</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Wheels</a></li>
</ol>
<ol class="a4" id="hide" style="-moz-column-count:1; -webkit-column-count:1; column-count:1; -moz-column-gap:30px; -webkit-column-gap:30px; column-gap:30px;">
    <li><a href="">Bells</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Computers</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Lights</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Locks</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Mudguards</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Pumps</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Stickers</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Water Bottle Cages</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Water Bottles</a></li>
</ol>
<div class="list4" id="hidding2">
    <ol class="forks4">
        <a href="">Front Suspension</a></ol>
    <ol class="comp4">
        <a href="">Components</a></ol>
    <ol class="wheel4">
        <a href="">Wheels &amp; Tyres</a></ol>
    <ol class="acc4">
        <a href="">Accessories</a></ol>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("[id^=hide]").hide();
    $("[id^=hidding1]").hide();
    $("[id^=hidding2]").hide();
    $("[id^=hidden1]").hide();
    $("[id^=hidden2]").hide();
    $("[id^=hidden3]").hide();
    $("[id^=hidden4]").hide();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img.headerlogoBTN").mouseenter(function(){
        $("img.headerlogoBTNOVER").css("visibility", "visible")
    })
    $(".headerlogo").mouseleave(function(){
        $("img.headerlogoBTNOVER").css("visibility", "hidden")
    })
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".allcategoriesBTN").mouseenter(function(){
        $("[id^=hidden1]").show();
        $("[id^=hidden2]").hide();
        $("[id^=hidden3]").hide();
        $("[id^=hidden4]").hide();
        $("[id^=hide]").hide();
        $("[id^=hidding1]").hide();
        $(".list1").show();
        $(".list2").hide();
        $(".list3").hide();
        $(".list4").hide();
    })
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".allbrandsBTN").mouseenter(function(){
        $("[id^=hidden1]").hide();
        $("[id^=hidden2]").show();
        $("[id^=hidden3]").hide();
        $("[id^=hidden4]").hide();
        $("[id^=hide]").hide();
        $("[id^=hidding1]").hide();
        $(".list1").hide();
        $(".list2").show();
        $(".list3").hide();
        $(".list4").hide();
    })
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".mtbbikesBTN").mouseenter(function(){
        $("[id^=hidden1]").hide();
        $("[id^=hidden2]").hide();
        $("[id^=hidden3]").show();
        $("[id^=hidden4]").hide();
        $("[id^=hide]").hide();
        $("[id^=hidding1]").hide();
        $(".list1").hide();
        $(".list2").hide();
        $(".list3").show();
        $(".list4").hide();
    })
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".roadbikesBTN").mouseenter(function(){
        $("[id^=hidden1]").hide();
        $("[id^=hidden2]").hide();
        $("[id^=hidden3]").hide();
        $("[id^=hidden4]").show();
        $("[id^=hide]").hide();
        $("[id^=hidding1]").hide();
        $(".list1").hide();
        $(".list2").hide();
        $(".list3").hide();
        $(".list4").show();
    })
});

var myTimer;
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div.wrap").mouseenter(function(){
        clearTimeout(myTimer);
    })
    $(".background").mouseover(function(){
        clearTimeout(myTimer);
    })
    $("#hide").mouseover(function(){
        clearTimeout(myTimer);
    })
    $("#hidding1").mouseover(function(){
        clearTimeout(myTimer);
    })
    $("#hidding2").mouseover(function(){
        clearTimeout(myTimer);
    })
    $("div.wrap").mouseleave(function(){
        myTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        $("[id^=hidden1]").hide();
        $("[id^=hidden2]").hide();
        $("[id^=hidden3]").hide();
        $("[id^=hidden4]").hide();
        $("[id^=hide]").hide();
        $("[id^=hidding1]").hide();
        $("[id^=hidding2]").hide();
        $(".list1").hide();
        $(".list2").hide();
        $(".list3").hide();
        $(".list4").hide();
    }, 800);
    })
});

$(document).ready(function() {
$(".forks1").mouseenter(function() {
    $("[id^=hidding1]").hide();
    $("[id^=hide]").hide();
    $(".fs1header").show();
    $(".fs1").show();
    $(".sublistBTN").show();
    $(".sublistBTN").css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: "43px",
    })
});
$(".comp1").mouseenter(function() {
    $("[id^=hidding1]").hide();
    $("[id^=hide]").hide();
    $(".c1header").show();
    $(".c1").show();
    $(".sublistBTN").show();
    $(".sublistBTN").css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: "83px",
    })
})
$(".wheel1").mouseenter(function() {
    $("[id^=hidding1]").hide();
    $("[id^=hide]").hide();
    $(".wt1header").show();
    $(".wt1").show();
    $(".sublistBTN").show();
    $(".sublistBTN").css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: "121px",
    })
})
$(".acc1").mouseenter(function() {
    $("[id^=hidding1]").hide();
    $("[id^=hide]").hide();
    $(".a1header").show();
    $(".a1").show();
    $(".sublistBTN").show();
    $(".sublistBTN").css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: "161px",
    })
})
});

$(document).ready(function() {
$(".forks2").mouseenter(function() {
    $("[id^=hidding1]").hide();
    $("[id^=hide]").hide();
    $(".fs2header").show();
    $(".fs2").show();
    $(".sublistBTN").show();
    $(".sublistBTN").css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: "43px",
    })
});
$(".comp2").mouseenter(function() {
    $("[id^=hidding1]").hide();
    $("[id^=hide]").hide();
    $(".c2header").show();
    $(".c2").show();
    $(".sublistBTN").show();
    $(".sublistBTN").css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: "83px",
    })
})
$(".wheel2").mouseenter(function() {
    $("[id^=hidding1]").hide();
    $("[id^=hide]").hide();
    $(".wt2header").show();
    $(".wt2").show();
    $(".sublistBTN").show();
    $(".sublistBTN").css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: "121px",
    })
})
$(".acc2").mouseenter(function() {
    $("[id^=hidding1]").hide();
    $("[id^=hide]").hide();
    $(".a2header").show();
    $(".a2").show();
    $(".sublistBTN").show();
    $(".sublistBTN").css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: "161px",
    })
})
});

$(document).ready(function() {
$(".forks3").mouseenter(function() {
    $("[id^=hidding1]").hide();
    $("[id^=hide]").hide();
    $(".fs3header").show();
    $(".fs3").show();
    $(".sublistBTN").show();
    $(".sublistBTN").css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: "43px",
    })
});
$(".comp3").mouseenter(function() {
    $("[id^=hidding1]").hide();
    $("[id^=hide]").hide();
    $(".c3header").show();
    $(".c3").show();
    $(".sublistBTN").show();
    $(".sublistBTN").css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: "83px",
    })
})
$(".wheel3").mouseenter(function() {
    $("[id^=hidding1]").hide();
    $("[id^=hide]").hide();
    $(".wt3header").show();
    $(".wt3").show();
    $(".sublistBTN").show();
    $(".sublistBTN").css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: "121px",
    })
})
$(".acc3").mouseenter(function() {
    $("[id^=hidding1]").hide();
    $("[id^=hide]").hide();
    $(".a3header").show();
    $(".a3").show();
    $(".sublistBTN").show();
    $(".sublistBTN").css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: "161px",
    })
})
});

$(document).ready(function() {
$(".forks4").mouseenter(function() {
    $("[id^=hidding1]").hide();
    $("[id^=hide]").hide();
    $(".fs4header").show();
    $(".fs4").show();
    $(".sublistBTN").show();
    $(".sublistBTN").css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: "43px",
    })
});
$(".comp4").mouseenter(function() {
    $("[id^=hidding1]").hide();
    $("[id^=hide]").hide();
    $(".c4header").show();
    $(".c4").show();
    $(".sublistBTN").show();
    $(".sublistBTN").css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: "83px",
    })
})
$(".wheel4").mouseenter(function() {
    $("[id^=hidding1]").hide();
    $("[id^=hide]").hide();
    $(".wt4header").show();
    $(".wt4").show();
    $(".sublistBTN").show();
    $(".sublistBTN").css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: "121px",
    })
})
$(".acc4").mouseenter(function() {
    $("[id^=hidding1]").hide();
    $("[id^=hide]").hide();
    $(".a4header").show();
    $(".a4").show();
    $(".sublistBTN").show();
    $(".sublistBTN").css({
        position: "absolute",
        top: "161px",
    })
})
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the overall problem is, but 1 thing, you should only have 1 $(document).ready(); event per js script.  1 event that would call three functions, not 3 events running there own code.

Comment: You also have a `meta` tag outside your `head`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it is a positioning issue. Try updating your .wrap class to this.

```
.wrap {
      position: relative;
      top: 0px;
      /* left: 145px; */
      margin: -34px 0 0 145px;
 }
```

Comment: Yep positional error, i just placed that code in and positioned it back up and it works fine.